# Codeigniter ckeditor form problems

Tags: codeigniter, post, filter, ckeditor

I am using a combination of codeigniter's form helper and the ckeditor to attempt to send html to my server, save it into the database, and then sent it back to the browser for re-editing.

To accomplish this, a am:

1. creating a textarea using codeigniter's `form_textarea()` function.
2. (optional)using `CKEDITOR.replace` to turn that textarea into a
   ckeditor field.
3. pasting html into the field.
4. submitting the field as POST and retrieving it using codeigniter's
   `input->post();`
5. inserting the data into the database using codeigniter's
   `db->insert()`
6. pulling the data using ci's `db->get()`
7. putting it back into a textarea using `form_textarea()` again.

after performing this cycle a couple of times, the html just disappears during a post operation.  I am assuming that this is being caused by some characters that need to be escaped, but I am at a loss for why this is happening and how to fix it.

It usually happens after the html is pulled form the database, put into the textarea, then resubmitted.  I also noticed that if I activate the CKEditor each time the page is reloaded, the problem does not happen.

If anyone has faced this problem before, please tell me how you managed to deal with the text so that it loaded, submitted, saved and reloaded without problems.  Also, anything useful that could be said about codeigniter's filters would be great too.  Thanks

Note: using CKEditor for every field, all the time is not really an option.

I have included a body of text that causes this problem:

This text is pasted into the text area:

```
<p>Ownar and Flaght Daractar af Mass Madaa Labs, Jan Mass as a dagatal markatang stratagast and craatava madaa spacaalast wath avar 20 yaars af axparaanca warkang wath basanass awnars and axacatavas. Ha has warkad wath namaraas campanaas ta davalap thaar Dagatal Starytallang, Cantant Stratagy/Davalapmant, PR/Crasas Managamant, and Sacaal Madaa Prasanca. Jan has spakan at canfarancas an tapacs rangang fram 'LankadIn far Prafassaanals' ta 'Sacaal Madaa On Tha Ga' far basy axacatavas. Has na-nansansa appraach ta asang anlana taals cats thraagh tha hypa and facasas an tha cara raasans far prafassaanals ta asa thasa taals, fallawad ap wath traanang an affactava asa af anlana taals. Nat jast an adacatar, Jan as actavaly asang anlana taals ta attract, angaga and rataan has targat aadaanca whach makas ham an adaal anstractar far thasa laakang ta tap tha kanatac anargy af tha Intarnat; Mr. Mass as an adraat and saccassfal practataanar af all ha taachas and wratas.&nbsp;<br /><br />Jan Mass, an awasama vadaagraphar and phatagraphar, as alsa tha faandar af Basanass Chattanaaga, tha largast LankadIn graap an Chattanaaga araa, and tha craatar af BasanassChatt.cam - a blag far antrapranaars &amp; prafassaanals lavang/warkang/playang an tha Chattanaaga, TN araa.</p>
```

After passing through the database, and back into another textarea, it looks like this:

```
<p>Ownar and Flaght Daractar af Mass Madaa Labs, Jan Mass as a dagatal markatang stratagast and craatava madaa spacaalast wath avar 20 yaars af axparaanca warkang wath basanass awnars and axacatavas. Ha has warkad wath namaraas campanaas ta davalap thaar Dagatal Starytallang, Cantant Stratagy/Davalapmant, PR/Crasas Managamant, and Sacaal Madaa Prasanca. Jan has spakan at canfarancas an tapacs rangang fram 'LankadIn far Prafassaanals' ta 'Sacaal Madaa On Tha Ga' far basy axacatavas. Has na-nansansa appraach ta asang anlana taals cats thraagh tha hypa and facasas an tha cara raasans far prafassaanals ta asa thasa taals, fallawad ap wath traanang an affactava asa af anlana taals. Nat jast an adacatar, Jan as actavaly asang anlana taals ta attract, angaga and rataan has targat aadaanca whach makas ham an adaal anstractar far thasa laakang ta tap tha kanatac anargy af tha Intarnat; Mr. Mass as an adraat and saccassfal practataanar af all ha taachas and wratas. <br /><br />Jan Mass, an awasama vadaagraphar and phatagraphar, as alsa tha faandar af Basanass Chattanaaga, tha largast LankadIn graap an Chattanaaga araa, and tha craatar af BasanassChatt.cam - a blag far antrapranaars & prafassaanals lavang/warkang/playang an tha Chattanaaga, TN araa.</p>
```

Now, if i resubmit it, the data never appears in the POST array.  However, if i activate the ckeditor before I sublit this text, it is transformed into:

```
<p>Ownar and Flaght Daractar af Mass Madaa Labs, Jan Mass as a dagatal markatang stratagast and craatava madaa spacaalast wath avar 20 yaars af axparaanca warkang wath basanass awnars and axacatavas. Ha has warkad wath namaraas campanaas ta davalap thaar Dagatal Starytallang, Cantant Stratagy/Davalapmant, PR/Crasas Managamant, and Sacaal Madaa Prasanca. Jan has spakan at canfarancas an tapacs rangang fram &#39;LankadIn far Prafassaanals&#39; ta &#39;Sacaal Madaa On Tha Ga&#39; far basy axacatavas. Has na-nansansa appraach ta asang anlana taals cats thraagh tha hypa and facasas an tha cara raasans far prafassaanals ta asa thasa taals, fallawad ap wath traanang an affactava asa af anlana taals. Nat jast an adacatar, Jan as actavaly asang anlana taals ta attract, angaga and rataan has targat aadaanca whach makas ham an adaal anstractar far thasa laakang ta tap tha kanatac anargy af tha Intarnat; Mr. Mass as an adraat and saccassfal practataanar af all ha taachas and wratas.&nbsp;<br /><br />Jan Mass, an awasama vadaagraphar and phatagraphar, as alsa tha faandar af Basanass Chattanaaga, tha largast LankadIn graap an Chattanaaga araa, and tha craatar af BasanassChatt.cam - a blag far antrapranaars &amp; prafassaanals lavang/warkang/playang an tha Chattanaaga, TN araa.</p>
```

Which makes it through without any problems.  However, on the next time around, the text that appears in the textarea is:

```
<p>Ownar and Flaght Daractar af Mass Madaa Labs, Jan Mass as a dagatal markatang stratagast and craatava madaa spacaalast wath avar 20 yaars af axparaanca warkang wath basanass awnars and axacatavas. Ha has warkad wath namaraas campanaas ta davalap thaar Dagatal Starytallang, Cantant Stratagy/Davalapmant, PR/Crasas Managamant, and Sacaal Madaa Prasanca. Jan has spakan at canfarancas an tapacs rangang fram 'LankadIn far Prafassaanals' ta 'Sacaal Madaa On Tha Ga' far basy axacatavas. Has na-nansansa appraach ta asang anlana taals cats thraagh tha hypa and facasas an tha cara raasans far prafassaanals ta asa thasa taals, fallawad ap wath traanang an affactava asa af anlana taals. Nat jast an adacatar, Jan as actavaly asang anlana taals ta attract, angaga and rataan has targat aadaanca whach makas ham an adaal anstractar far thasa laakang ta tap tha kanatac anargy af tha Intarnat; Mr. Mass as an adraat and saccassfal practataanar af all ha taachas and wratas. <br />
<br />
Jan Mass, an awasama vadaagraphar and phatagraphar, as alsa tha faandar af Basanass Chattanaaga, tha largast LankadIn graap an Chattanaaga araa, and tha craatar af BasanassChatt.cam - a blag far antrapranaars & prafassaanals lavang/warkang/playang an tha Chattanaaga, TN araa.</p>
```

Which will not make it though the POST array unless ckeditor is activated again.

Comment: Do you have `config.htmlEncodeOutput = false;` and `config.entities = true;` in your CKEditor `config.js`?

Comment: I have not changes any of the ckediter settings.  Currently, it is the only thing that seems to work.

Comment: Try my suggestion. See what happens.

Comment: THanks for the suggestion, but the point is to make the submissions work without the use of the ckeditor.  I am attempting to fix the problem using the following string replacements on the textareas when the form is submitted:

I added the following replacements to remove special characters and line breaks (The submissions work fine now):

replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
replace(/[^A-Za-z 0-9 \.,\?""!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)-_=\+;:<>\/\\\|\}\{\[\]`~]*/g, '') ; 

I would like to know in advance if this will break anything though